# How to combine events into 1 method?

Tags: c#

by default, we add events in this way:

```
item1.Click += Click1;
item2.Click += Click2;

.....
private void Click1(){
    .....
}
private void  Click2(){
}
```

however, is there a way to combine it into one method, like:

```
item1.Click += Click(1);
item2.Click += Click(2);
....
private void Click(int num){
  if(num==1){
     ....
  }
  else if(num==2){
     ....
  }
}
```

(btw, newbie in C#)

Comment: Is it your custom event or do you use WPF/WebForms/Asp's event?

Comment: We *don't* add events this way. You can use the same event handler for multiple events. The typical signature is `(sender,arguments)` so you *don't* need to specify who the sender is either

Comment: @BrootsWaymb the code already knows which event fires and which handler to call

Comment: The Event parameter(s) contain the device name so you do not have to pass it as a new parameter.

Comment: @jdweng can you show me an exmple how to find out which click was fired within one method?

Comment: @jdweng thanks, i was answered !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how events always worked. You can use the same event handler for multiple events as long as the signature is the same. The base [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) type accepts a `sender` which is the object that *fires* the event and an `EventArgs`-derived parameter which is probided when the code fires the event.

For example, you can have a single click handler for multiple buttons :

```
void myHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var theButton=(Button)sender;
    .....
}

button1.Click+=myHandler;
button2.Click+=myHandler;
button3.Click+=myHandler;
button4.Click+=myHandler;
```

Imagine you wanted to create a calculator with 10 digits. You could read the Text or Tag property of the sender to retrieve the digit :

```
void myDigitsHandler(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var theButton=(Button)sender;
    //You could store a number to the tag
    int digitFromTag=(int)theButton.Tag;

    //Or you could parse the text
    int digitFromText=int.Parse(theButton.Text);
    .....
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how i evaluate check ? is this correct: `if(theButton == button1)` ? or how i find out which one was clicked, using ID or?? 
thnx

Comment: With controls/buttons you can avoid checking by reading eg the Text or Tag property. That's useful when you only want to perform the same task for each button changing only a single parameter. Otherwise it's better to create separate handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Event handlers have `sender` argument usually which can be used to identify the actual sender:

```
void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn= (Button)sender; // you can access properties which you might have set to identify which button it is 
    .....
}

button1.Click+=Click;
button2.Click+=Click;
button3.Click+=Click;
button4.Click+=Click;
```

It this is not sufficient and you want to pass some extra data to the handler, you could use a lambda :

```
void Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int extraInfo)
{
    var btn= (Button)sender;
    .....
}

button1.Click+=(s, e) => Click(s, e, 1);
button2.Click+=(s, e) => Click(s, e, 2);
button3.Click+=(s, e) => Click(s, e, 3);
button4.Click+=(s, e) => Click(s, e, 4);
```

Unsubscribing will be an issue with anonymous methods but if the handler owner and the control have the same lifespan inside a page then it might not matter as they will get GC-ed together anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can also compare the sender by reference:

```
item1.Click += Click;
item2.Click += Click;
....
void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control c = sender as Control;     // c = null if sender is not Control

    if (sender == item1)
        Debug.Print(c.Name + ", " + c.Text + ", " + c.Tag);
    else if (sender == item2)
        Debug.Print(c.Name + ", " + c.Text + ", " + c.Tag);
}
```